# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and unit test SharePoint 2010 w/ MSTtest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, mstest

Could someone please clarify this MSDN article regarding Basic Unit Testing Support for the .NET Framework 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442059.aspx#bkmk_basicunittesting which states "The following capabilities enable developers to write unit tests and integration tests for applications that target the .NET Framework 3.5, including SharePoint 2010 applications".

The testing I've done and my understanding of the .Net 4.0 CLR and MsTest is that you can load .Net 3.5 assemblies into the 4.0 runtime, which allows for unit testing assemblies that target the 3.5 framework with a unit test project that targets 4.0 framework. This should in theory make it possible to unit test SharePoint project with MsTest 4.0.

What MsTest does not do is run in a true 64 bit mode. Since SharePoint 2010 requires a 64 bit process you get "Error loading C:\PublicShare\64Bit - Copy\Test64Bit\bin\x64\Debug\Test64Bit.dll: Unable to load the test container 'C:\PublicShare\64Bit - Copy\Test64Bit\bin\x64\Debug\Test64Bit.dll' or one of its dependencies. If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process. Error details: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\PublicShare\64Bit - Copy\Test64Bit\bin\x64\Debug\Test64Bit.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." when you try to run a unit test against an assembly that targets the x64 framework, which SharePoint Object Model must do.

It seems to me that the statement made by Microsoft is misleading, incomplete or misleading. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: After further testing I am going to assume the documentation is not correct. I don't see how MsTest can support an x64 assembly under test. All suggestions on the web say to test x64, build in AnyCPU and run on x86. Not an option, so moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with SP1 beta? [SP1 was released today](http://bit.ly/g2CG4n) and I hear that this does work.